# (One/multi) dimensional or (Single/multi)faceted person

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, difference

I was wondering what do you call someone who has developed in just one single aspect of life OR in several aspects of their life?

Let's suppose someone who has studies his entire life and never took part in social activities! He only has learned how to be good at medicine and turned out to be a very knowledgeable physician. He doesn't know how to conduct himself in a  social setting or how he should treat a woman.
What do you call such a person who has improved only in one thing?

Here, I know two potentially useable adjectives:

> a. single-faceted 
> b. one-dimensional

To the contrary, please imagine an athlete who is an engineer at the same time and a great businessman as well. 
He has a good understanding of life and has a very good relationship with his wife. 
He's a genial person. He can take nice pics, enjoy traveling etc.
As you can immediately grasp, such an individual has developed his character in many aspects. 
Could you please tell me what you call him?

Here, I know two other adjectives:

> a. multifaceted 
> b. multidimensional

However, I have no clue which one can be used to describe a "person".

PS. I looked them up in dictionaries. Dictionaries are not helpful enough, though.

Comment: That was my own question @Maciej Stachowski. I made the thread a long time ago, however, unfortunately, I didn't receive a convincing answer to the question back then.

Comment: Please do not repost duplicate questions. You can edit the old question if you want to tweak it, or put a bounty on it (I'm not sure of the details around when that's possible).

Comment: You'll also get the best results by adding any clarifications to the question itself. On the original question, you added many comments, but these should be edited into the question. Word requests should be accompanied by a sample sentence showing how the word would be used (it's not clear to me on the old or the duplicate post whether you're looking for a noun or an adjective).

Comment: socially ignorant or naive or stupid or uneducated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*multidimensional* (in the UK) is generally applied to abstract nouns like space, networks and issues rather than to people.

*multifaceted* is more commonly used to describe someone's character, personality or career than to describe the person. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multifaceted%20person%2Cmultifaceted%20personality%2Cmultifaceted%20character%2Cmultifaceted%20career&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmultifaceted%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultifaceted%20personality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultifaceted%20character%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultifaceted%20career%3B%2Cc0)

*single-faceted* (person) seems to be a rarity. *one-dimensional*, which is often applied to poorly-written characters in theatre, films and literature, is more colloquial. Applied to an acquaintance both are a little harsh.

To be *less* harsh, the word **rounded** might be useful.
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rounded) defines it thus:

> Well developed in all aspects; complete and balanced.
>  **Example**: ‘we should
> educate children to become rounded human beings’

So you might describe someone as well rounded and someone else as *not* a well rounded person.

Comment: well-rounded, I'd say. Fully rounded sounds like a barrel or bad posture to me.

Comment: Could you explain to me why you think this way @Lambie?

Comment: Because the cliché is: a well-rounded person. Not fully rounded.

Comment: You're right, @Lambie: Thanks. I've edited my answer. I was misled by one of the examples at that Lexico link, but I _thought_ it didn't sound quite right.